# LINQ expression for exact match of part of string in Entity framework

Tags: c#, regex, linq, entity-framework

I tried to get list of `MasterDto` using following query.But it didnt return expected result.So i want to get exact match results of given pattern.

```
 // Department Code like AB,ABC,BC,...etc.
    string jobNumberPrefixPattern= departmentCode; 

 MasterDto reportDto = unitOfWork.GetRepository<MasterDto>().LinqQuery
                                (m => m.CreateUserid.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()
                                      && m.JobNumberTemp.StartsWith(jobNumberPrefixPattern))
                                 .OrderByDescending(m => m.MasterPk)
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

`JobNumberTemp` is string field and its created based on departmentCode and next value of number.samples are like as follows.

- AB-0001
- AB-0002
- ABC-0001

Here I used `string.StartsWith` , instead of using this is there any suggestions to do ?

Comment: Any exception with this code?

Comment: nope but my result set is not i expected because of when i try to  filter  start with AB ,my query returns ABC as well

Comment: i edited my question sorry year should be removed from the jobNumber

Comment: What if you did `string jobNumberPrefixPattern = departmentCode + "-"; `. That will get translated to `LIKE 'jobNumberPrefixPattern%'` in SQL

Comment: "-" character is configurable and it can be changed in time to time.

Comment: When it changes, is that a retroactive change? (i.e. old numbers change too?). Then you could do `departmentCode + currentSeparator` in JIsaak's code.

Comment: nope thats the problem

Comment: Why do users never understand us developers!

Comment: Looks like you should do the first filtering by a `LIKE` query and refine the results in memory by using a regex that matches all possible separators immediately following the search term. Giving you "all possible separators" is the least they could do, couldn't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine. The value you're using for `jobNumberPrefixPattern` is the problem. ABC  starts with AB, if your pattern is AB then I returning ABC values is expected. If you want AB and not ABC you should use `AB-` as your jobNumberPrefix.

Comment: i am not allow to do that buddy

Comment: @Leez why are you not allowed to do that?

Comment: that is the requirement .it can be change in future.im developing it for client.

Comment: @Leez well you can use RegEx and have `AB[^a-Z]` as your expression but it would be better to change your requirements or parameterize the delimiter. Why would your delimiter change? The person writing your requirements is an idiot...